# Stopping a running script though another script file

Tags: bash, scripts

I am new to shell scripts. Say, I start a script like this. This runs for 3 days. So, I will start the script remotely through ssh and then close my local terminal.

**start.sh**

```
end=$((SECONDS+259200))
x=1
while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]
do
    #Some command
done
```

How will I write a `stop.sh` to stop the script whenever I want to stop it? I can modify `start.sh` as well if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few ways:

### Kill any instance of the script:

```
pkill -f start.sh
```

This will kill any process with `start.sh` in its command line, using [`pkill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pkill).

### Kill a specific instance of the script:

Modify the script to save its PID somewhere:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo $$ >> /tmp/start_sh.pid
end=...
```

And tell `stop.sh` to kill the process with the PID there:

```
#! /bin/bash
kill $(cat /tmp/start_sh.pid) || echo "Process is not running."
```

This will kill all `script.sh` processes.

### Communicate with `start.sh`

Tell `start.sh` to read from some file telling to quit:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]
do
    [[ $(cat ~/kill_start.txt) == "KILL" ]] && exit 1
    ...
```

And tell `stop.sh` to write "KILL" to that file:

```
#! /bin/bash   
echo "KILL" > ~/kill_start.sh
```

This will kill all instances of `start.sh`, when the next iteration of each script runs.

(Despite the name `kill_start.sh` is not a script.)

### Use named pipes to communicate

Alternatively, you can run a background job in the script to watch for changes to `~/kill_start.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
...
[[ -p ~/kill_script.sh ]] && mkfifo ~/kill_script.sh
(read -N 0 < ~/kill_script && [[ $REPLY == "KILL" ]] && kill 0) &

while [ $SECONDS -lt $end ]
do
    ...
```

In `stop.sh`, echo anything to `~/kill_script`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo anything at all
```

This will use [`mkfifo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mkfifo.1.html) to make a [named pipe](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node15.html). Then `read` will attempt to read from that pipe, and will wait until it gets any input at all, then proceed to [exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48542/70524). This should take effect almost immediately.

---

### Use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

With `screen`, you can start a shell via SSH, close your connection, and then resume it later. So you can start a `screen` session for the script, close your connection, go on holiday, come back, recall your screen connection and kill the script using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: The pkill -f method didn't work for me.